# Is it ok to use a 110V cable for a 110-220V device on a 220V Outlet?

Tags: cables

The focus here is the ***cable.***  Will the 110V cable be ok if It was used to connect between a 220V outlet and a device that has an input voltage of 110-220V?

Likewise, will it also be ok for a 220 volt cable to connect between a 220V outlet and a device that has an input voltage of 110-220V?

Among the two configurations above, which is better or safer and why? or is there no difference at all?

I'm asking this because I am unsure whether I also need to mind the maximum voltage rating of cables as well. I know its not good to plug a 220V device to a 110V outlet or vice versa however, I cannot find clear cut information yet on the internet ***specifically with regards to using cables of different max voltage ratings***.

Comment: Depends on the specifics of the particular cable.  If you have specs for the cable that say the rated voltage is "X" you should not exceed X.

Comment: Who is making a cable rated for 110 V but with a plug on the end that will fit one of the socket types used for 220 V?

Comment: This happens in the case of importing electronic goods from a 110V Country to a country that uses 220V. Lets say a computer monitor. Now a computer monitor comes with a IEC C13 power cord to a type B male plug. Since the 2 countries use different voltages, then this power cord can and should have 2 variations - a 110V one and a 220V one. The question in this post then lies if its ok to use a 110V power cord to connect towards a 220V outlet and a 220V device (or a dual voltage 110-220V device for that matter, if it makes any difference)

Answer (score 5):

You should never exceed the rated voltage of a cable.

In your two scenarios:

Using the 110 V rated cable to connect between a 220 V outlet and any device is a bad idea.

Connecting a 220 V rated cable between a 220 V outlet and 110-220 V device is just fine.

Being under the rated voltage for the cable is not a problem.

Comment: Ok that clears it. Thanks. I will be swapping out my IEC cables that are rated 110 Volts to 220 Volt ones, because my outlet is 220V. Most modern devices are 110-220V (Dual Voltage compatible), especially if companies want to export them to earn more $.

Comment: If you can sacrifice one, cut it open and look at the wires inside. Their jacketing might read "300V" or "150V".

Comment: @evildemonic I have another question 
Power = Voltage x Current 
Appliances will only draw how much power they need. 
However... Is the actual voltage within the cable constant with whatever wall socket's voltage it is connected to? (I.e. if wall socket wall voltage is 220 volts then the voltage of the cable you connect it to will also be 220 volts?). OR does the voltage vary? If so how is the voltage calculated? (Let's say a device draws 5 watts. How much voltage and current will it need?)

Comment: The voltage is constant (within reason) so the current drawn will vary depending on the device. As for your calculation:  A = 5W / 220V

Comment: Yes, the voltage is constant and will not vary.  The outlets in your house will provide the rated voltage up to the current that will trip the circuit breaker.  How much impedance your load has will determine the current.

Answer (score 0):

### There's no substitute for reading the labeling *on the cable*

A cable with no markings is "mystery meat" and cannot be used for *any* AC mains usage, since it is not rated for any usage.

Examples of North American cord types might be SJW, SJOW or SJOOW.

The cable markings will plainly state the cable type.  It will also either state the maximum voltage (typically 300V for common North American cordage stock, sometimes 600V).

**That is the last word on the subject**.

North American-sourced products  tend to be certified by an *independent* third party Recognized Testing Lab, such as the famous Underwriter's Laboratories (UL), [and others on a list](https://www.osha.gov/nationally-recognized-testing-laboratory-program) curated by USA's OSHA. Thousands of other agencies across many countries defer to that list.

UL both approves the product as initially designed and surveils manufacturing to assure quality does not falter.